# Sign convention in link

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, beam, statics

If we take the moment about A from the $F_{BC}$ will make the body want to rotate counter clock wise but If we take it from the point C it will make the body rotate clock wise whats the mistake?

[image]

Comment: CB seems like a rope, so it should basically transfer only tension in its direction.

Comment: your Fbcsintheta puts torque on the bar, torque doesn't transfer through pin A.  Plus, net torque on the bar is zero or it would move